# MongoDB and Deployd

Tags: mongodb, osx-mountain-lion, deployd

Looking to try out Deployd with MongoDB and an AngularJS front end. On my Mac I can get Node and Mongo to launch, but it requires launching mongod with the --config flag. I created a .conf file and launch it with the flag, each time directing it to the location of the .conf file. Deployd is attempting to launch mongodb but gets the same error I got initially trying to start mongod, which is that it can't read the config file.

I'm new to mongo and am having a rough time getting this to play nice. Am I missing something? I even installed it using Homebrew, which was supposed to go ahead and take care of these config issues, but I'm still not getting where I need to be.

Any clarification at this point would be helpful. I'm guessing that there's some simple thing that I've messed up along the way.

Comment: I don't know much about Deployd, but normally only a single instance of the mongod server would be running on your system.  What happens if you start mongod before starting Deployd?

Comment: Solved my own problem. Looking at the information that homebrew was looking for I took a look at where the plist file thought it was supposed to be. It looks for the appropriate config file in usr/local/etc. Problem was that the etc directory was actually an empty file, so nothing could be written there. Got rid of the file and created a directory. Reinstalled mongo and miraculously everything worked as advertised. Would have been great if I had known to look for this a day and a half ago.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and finally found out how it works.

if you want to use the mongodb dataset which was created by #deployd (you find it in the `data` folder) tell mongod the path of the folder and the port you want to listen on.

This is how you can start the mongodb server with the deployd dataset

`mongod --dbpath ./data/ --port 12345`

Next create a node.js script to start deployd which will listen to your mongodb.

```
var deployd = require('deployd');

var dpd = deployd({
  port: 2403,
  env: 'development',
  db: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 12345,
    name: '-deployd'
  }
});

dpd.listen();
```

This script with mongodb will create the exact situation than using the command `dpd`. However now you can use all other nodejs function.